# Why does "./a.out" only run the last compiled executable program and not the previous ones?

Tags: c++

I have taken my first two courses in java and now have to take Data Structures in C++. I'm trying to open up the different files I've compiled.

They're just two "Hello, world!" programs with slightly different text.

When I type:

```
g++ HelloWorld.cpp
```

The file "a.out" is created which I run by typing ./a.out into the command prompt.

Now that I compiled a second executable program, HelloWorldII.cpp, the a.out file only runs that program.

When I try to run ./HelloWorld.cpp I got permission denied, so I typed in:

```
sudo chmod 744 /Users/username/HelloWorld
```

to make me the owner of the folder which didn't work so I typed in:

```
sudo chown -R "$garyjones:" users/username/HelloWorld
```

to give the owner(me) permission to edit/open, after which when I attempted to run ./HelloWorld.cpp, terminal began to attempt executing it but instead showed me syntax error even though compiling them with g++ HelloWorld.cpp and running them with their a.out files worked fine.

If I have multiple executable files in a folder, how can I open the one I want?

Comment: *.cpp files need to be compiled to binary executable before it can be executed.

Comment: [Compiling with g++](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/00wi/unix/g++.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile and link code, the executable is by default named `a.out` - you are supposed to add a parameter to the linking to name it.

If you don’t do it, they are all going to be named `a.out`, and of course overwrite each other - there can be only one file with that name.

Comment: That parameter is `-o` for output. e.g. `$ g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld`

Answer (score 0):

It is strange for you attempting to execute a pure ascii text file. You don't understand the execution mode's meaning. You are not familiar with g++. It seems like you don't know the process of how an executable file generated by compiler from source file.

And here is my advice.

1. Google the basic usage of g++ or some other compilers. Choose your favourite.

Here is the temporary solution.

```
g++ <source file> -o <executable filename>
```

Example:

```
## if you don't specific a name for the binary file, 
## it will generate a.out and delete the exiting a.out firstly
g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld
## and then you can execute it 
./HelloWorld
```

2. Figure out what the exact meaning of file permission.
3. The a.out filename has traditional reason and I recommend you to explore it. It's funny.